# onclick pass two variables to php with jquery (vote system)

Tags: php, jquery, vote

I have 5 stars system in html/smarty below

```
<ul class="star-rating" id="{$ID}">
<li><a href="#" class="one-star"></a></li>
<li><a href="#" class="two-stars"></a></li>
<li><a href="#" class="three-stars"></a></li>
<li><a href="#" class="four-stars"></a></li>
<li><a href="#" class="five-stars"></a></li>
</ul>

<div style="display:none;" id="ok">Vote submited</div>
<div style="display:none;" id="wrong">Wrong</div>
<div style="display:none;" id="loggedin">Log in to vote</div>
```

ul blocks has own ID. I need to pass witch star has been pressed and get ul id, theen this data need to be passed to php and get response, theen response need to fade out. I came up with some basic code below, but it need's to be finished and fixed. Would be gratefull if anyone would be helpfull ?

```
$( ".star-rating" ).click(function() {

    $.ajax({ 
        type: "POST",
        url: "js/ajax.php",
        data: "id" + id, "score" + score,
        success: function(pass) {
                      // all ok
            if(pass == '1') 
                 $("#ok").show();
                      // something went wrong
            else if(pass == '2') 
                 $("#wrong").show();
                         // you need to be logged in to vote
            else if(pass == '3') 
                 $("#loggedin").show();
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want to bind to the `a` and not the `ul`:

```
$('ul.star-rating').on('click', 'a', function() { // jquery 1.7+
  var score = this.className,
      ul = $(this).closest('ul'),
      id = ul[0].id;

  $.ajax({ 
        type: "POST",
        url: "js/ajax.php",
        data: {id: id, score: score}, // fixed formatting here
        success: function(pass) {
                      // all ok
            if(pass == '1') 
                 $("#ok").show().delay(5000).fadeOut(); // here is one way to do a fade out
                      // something went wrong
            else if(pass == '2') 
                 $("#wrong").show();
                         // you need to be logged in to vote
            else if(pass == '3') 
                 $("#loggedin").show();
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

Note also the delay in your succes callback as one way to do a fade.

Comment: It works thx Jed, but now i need to show result <div id="ok">Vote submited</div> under ul block wich i pressed href, what would be the fastest way to achievie it?. In html i could do something like this, <div style="display:none;" class="ok" id="{$ID}">Vote submited</div>, theen in javascript how should it look $("#ok").show().delay(5000).fadeOut(); ?

Comment: It should work like you want as long as ajax.php is returning '1'. Are you sure it's returning that value for pass?

Comment: It returns 1 because i put that by hand there. Basically script works but i got many ul blocks and under every got messages, logic tell me i would need to specify witch div needs to be shown isn;t that right?

Comment: Better would be to have one #msg div that you fill with the result of the request. So ajax.php either returns the message to show there -  `$('#msg').html(pass)` - or you do an `if/then` inside the success callback to interpret the returned value and specify the message value accordingly.

Comment: You don't understand me right. I need to have one separate div msg box for every instance of ul block. Because wheen i press star to vote on, msg need to be shown under that particular box, not in one static place. As to your answer, yes I can do that. But that is just cosmetic.

Comment: Just have a div after each ul and give it id `msg-{$ID}`. Then to write the message in it, do `$(msg + '-' + id).html(...)`.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously, you need to get the ID and the score.

The ID is from the UL, and can be gotten like so:

```
var id = $(this).closest('ul').attr('id')
```

The star rating is from the class, you're gonna need to get all the classes (if there are others added), and get the rating.

```
var liClass = $(this).attr('class').split(' '), score;
$.each(liClass, function(i,v){
    if(v.indexOf('-star') !== -1){
      score = v;
      return false;
    }
});
```